# Authentication Error with Github Actions when try to publish to Node.js Github packages

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to publish npm package to Github packages using Github actions.
It is TS service that compile protofiles to interfaces to be imported and used in other servicies

But i receive error `` npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser ``

Here is the workflow file

```
  workflow_dispatch: # Triggered manually from the Actions tab

jobs:
  publish-gpr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.10.0
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/

      - run: git config user.email "****g@gmail.com"
      - run: git config user.name "*****"

      - name: Install protoc
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update -qq
          sudo apt-get install -qq protobuf-compiler

      - name: Install deps
        run: |
          cd packages/protobuff && yarn install

      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd packages/protobuff && yarn run build

      - name: Authenticate with npm
        run: echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=\${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}" > ~/.npmrc
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: publish to github
        run: |
          cd packages/protobuff && npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Error log:

```
Run cd packages/protobuff && npm publish
npm notice 
npm notice   @techcare/protobuff@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 467B  bin/protobuild                 
npm notice 131B  dist/index.d.ts                
npm notice 172B  dist/index.d.ts.map            
npm notice 284B  dist/index.js                  
npm notice 675B  dist/ts-proto-gen/test.d.ts    
npm notice 609B  dist/ts-proto-gen/test.d.ts.map
npm notice 1.2kB dist/ts-proto-gen/test.js      
npm notice 770B  package.json                   
npm notice 209B  protos/test.proto              
npm notice 156B  src/index.ts                   
npm notice 1.3kB src/ts-proto-gen/test.ts       
npm notice 315B  tsconfig.json                  
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          @techcare/protobuff                     
npm notice version:       1.0.0                                   
npm notice filename:      @techcare/protobuff-1.0.0.tgz           
npm notice package size:  2.2 kB                                  
npm notice unpacked size: 6.3 kB                                  
npm notice shasum:        4839e75cb3bbdccc9d624ff6a15f05ae25c05bbb
npm notice integrity:     sha512-/KAXMamz97Kkm[...]hEOqHct7iea6w==
npm notice total files:   12                                      
npm notice 
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-12-04T14_06_12_215Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

package.json:

```
  "name": "@techcare/protobuff",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": "git@github.com:nikolabozicbg/techcare.git",
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "yarn install && yarn run lint && yarn run --silent build",
    "build": "rm -rf ./dist && yarn build:proto && tsc",
    "build:proto": "./bin/protobuild",
    "publish:github": "npm publish --registry https://npm.pkg.github.com/ --ignore-scripts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.9.12",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.2.10",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.2.10",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^10.2.10",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "rxjs": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-proto": "^1.69.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why it   requires you to be logged in to https://registry.npmjs.org/